# Ten numbers per row using a pair of nested while loops

Tags: python

I was trying to do an exercise, but have a hard time doing it. I need to write a program containing a pair of nested while loops that displays the integer values 1-100, ten per row. I'm not sure how I should use while loops in such a task, I was trying something like this, but it seems like it only gives me first line to 10 and then all other numbers in second line:

```
i = 1
while i <=100:
    print(i, end=' ')
    i = i + 1
```

Any advice?

Comment: You've been told to use a pair of nested `while` loops. So far you have neither `while` loops nor a pair of nested loops.

Comment: I'm confused where to put any, for example, should I somehow use while instead of ''for i in range(1, 101)''?

Comment: Yes, exactly. See the tutorial, starting https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming

Comment: @Dinozauras yes - that appears to be what you're being asked to do... try writing a loop that increments a counter `while` the counter is less than another value to start with...

Comment: thanks guys, have edited my code, now I on my way to make it 10 integers per row, but could it be also made using while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope This will help

```
#python 2.7.6

for i in range(1, 101):
    print(i),
    if i%10==0:
        print
```

another solution with nested while loop:

```
loop1 = 10
loop2 = 10
num = 1

while(loop1>0):
    while(loop2>0):
        print num,
        num = num+1
        loop2=loop2-1
    print
    loop2=10
    loop1=loop1-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I did the job right, thanks guys for helping me out.

```
i = 1
per_row = 10
while i <=100:
    while(per_row > 0):
        print(i, end=' ')
        i = i + 1
        per_row = per_row - 1
    print()
    per_row = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit cleaner one:

```
i = 1
column = 10

while i <= 100:
    if column > 0:
        if i < 10:
            print(format('', '1') + str(i), end = ' ')
        else:
            print(i, end = ' ')

        i = i + 1
        column = column - 1
    else:
        print()
        column = 10
```